# QB64 Console/Display Font Size

Tags: basic, qbasic, qb64

I am tutoring someone in my high school in QBasic and the QB64 font is really small making it difficult to edit it. How can I change the font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the IDE the font can be changed in options (Alt-O) in the Display settings.

Comment: The fonts are .ttf files and can be found in c:\windows\fonts\

Answer (score 0):

Go to option section in top row:
Select display in down arrow
increase the size in pixels: 30
Note: size in pixes may differ from size of monitor so choose as per  your display screen

[image]